# Sql Copy table from One Database to Another Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to copy a table from one database to another. So I tried to query in SqlFiddle as follows but getting error

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    (`id` int, `productName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    (`id`, `productName`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'OpenIDM', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
    (2, 'OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
    (3, 'OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java')
;


CREATE TABLE ForgeRock1 AS SELECT * FROM ForgeRock
```

Error:

> DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema panel.

Comment: As the error states, SQLFiddle doesn't let you put CREATE TABLE statements in the box on the right.  Put it in the box on the left.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f1c9/1

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `mysqldump` to dump a table into another database:

```
mysqldump -u<user> -p<password> <first_database> <table_name> | mysql -u<user> -p<password> <second_database>
```

Of course the second database must then first be created, which can be done using a command like:

```
mysql -u<user> -p<password> -e"CREATE DATABASE <second_database>"
```

Comment: I think her question is more of a SQL Fiddle problem rather than a MySQL question.  Too bad the title doesn't mention this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL `INSERT INTO...SELECT` syntax to achieve what you want.

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock1
    (`id` int, `productName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55));

INSERT INTO ForgeRock1 SELECT * FROM ForgeRock
```

Comment: @LalitJadiya I updated my answer so that it runs in SQL Fiddle.  Try again.  You need to put the `INSERT` statement on the left.